# How can I determine which Pull Request a commit belongs to using the GitHub API?

Tags: travis-ci, github-api

Given a commit SHA, I'd like to use the GitHub API to determine which pull request it belongs to.

GitHub displays this information on the [commit page](https://github.com/hammerlab/pileup.js/commit/ee49f07dba3821109b3cf45404446f434a897558):

[image: PR link for a commit]

This information isn't in the API response for that commit, however:

```
curl --silent 'https://api.github.com/repos/hammerlab/pileup.js/commits/ee49f07dba3821109b3cf45404446f434a897558' | grep 328
(nothing)
```

Is it possible to get this information using the GitHub API? I realize that I could crawl all the recent PRs for the repo, but this seems inefficient.

For context: I'd like to do this from a Travis-CI "push" job, where I have access to the SHA but not any information about whether it's part of a pull request.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible, using the [Search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/), which supports this feature:

https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/#search-by-the-commit-shas-within-a-pull-request

For example:

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=ee49f07dba3821109b3cf45404446f434a897558
```

returns a single result, which is this pull request:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/hammerlab/pileup.js/issues/328
```

Comment: It works but for some commit hashes this outputs multiple pull requests containing the same commit hash. Check this link[https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=40abe126a31121bf9a27ee1fe46b500cd958a0ac] in this kind of scenario what pull request we should consider as the pull request which merge that commit

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya I'd consider the one which was merged first. You can get that information via the API as well (when a pull request was merged).

Answer (score 19):

It seems to be possible using this new feature in the API v.3:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-pull-requests-associated-with-a-commit

This URL now redirects to:

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-pull-requests-associated-with-a-commit

This is the syntax:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:commit_sha/pulls
```

Comment: This worked for me with Cloud Build. Cloud Build passes in `$COMMIT_SHA` for merge triggers and this value can be used with the above API endpoint to get the PR that triggered the build.