# Use Search API for Pull Requests with go-github

Tags: github-api, go-github

**Scenario**: I receive a [status webhook event](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#status) from GitHub. I want to find any Pull Requests associated with the commit.

The [StatusEvent](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-github/v42/github#StatusEvent) contains the commit `.SHA` and a `.Repo` (Respository) object. This *appears* to be sufficient to find applicable PRs.

**Issue**: If the `status` event is triggered in response to checks performed on a PR in a respository separate from the commit, there are problems...

**Attempt 1**: The go-github package contains a [PullRequestsService](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-github/v42/github#PullRequestsService) with [.ListPullRequestsWithCommit](https://github.com/google/go-github/blob/715804611970b1342b4ba8f6912ca001d391bf38/github/pulls.go#L174) method calling [this GitHub API method](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/commits#list-pull-requests-associated-with-a-commit). Unfortunately, this only seems to return PRs within the repo containing the commit. Meaning, it appears to ignore PRs created with commits from forked repos.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33307413/1580288

Answer (score 0):

**Attempt 2**: go-github has a [SearchService.Issues](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-github/v42/github#SearchService.Issues) method which accepts a `query` parameter. Using parameters `type:pr SHA:<sha>`, you get the issue "backing" the PR (not sure the proper terminology) -- regardless of the originating repo.

Then, using the [PullRequestsService.Get](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-github/v42/github#PullRequestsService.Get) method, you can get the actual [PullRequest](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-github/v42/github#PullRequest) data.

**Prototype code** (use at your own risk):

```
commitSha := event.GetCommit().GetSHA()
ownerLogin := repo.GetOwner().GetLogin()

issues, _, err := client.Search.Issues(ctx, fmt.Sprintf("type:pr SHA:%s", commitSha), &github.SearchOptions{})
// if err != nil { ??? }
// if len(issues.Issues) == 0 { ??? }
issue := issue.Issue[0]
pr, _, err := client.PullRequests.Get(ctx, ownerLogin, issue.GetNumber())
// if err != nil { ??? }
```